# ReactJS typical workflow - from development to deployment

Tags: reactjs, git, workflow, scrum

My use case is composed of several ReactJs projects, where we collaborate using Git.

we are building a workflow to be used using Git, and that's our current thinking:

1. Each programmer works locally feching the `next` branch
2. They build their own branches but at the end its all merged to `next`
3. When all the pending tasks are done, we move create a branch `test` from `next`
4. Once `test` is fine, it is branched to `beta`
5. When stable, branched `stable`

This is the development phase.

For deployment, our first tought is to "build" the bundle on `test`, `beta` and `stabe` and copy it to the respective servers for running, as we keep built bundles on a normal filesystem (this is how we do it today, keep several bundles for several versions, not using Git)

Our production environment has dozen of servers in different customers, and every time we need to update, we need to copy the respective bundle from the correct directory to the server and install it (all bundles are build with an installation tool).

So, I have 2 doubts here:

a) Is the development workflow a good practice? Any suggestion?

b) How we make the deployment workflow smoother? Should we keep the bundles together in the code on Git ? Should we use something different?

Ideally we would need the server to autoupdate from our command. What would be the correct way to accomplish that ?